# Battery depleting on second prototype

Tags: esp8266, battery, rf, arduino-mini

I am working on a project which uses two 18650 3400ma batteries to power some sensors, an Arduino Mini Pro, an 433mhz RF transmitter and an ESP8266-01. Most of the time the Arduino is in sleep mode and I only wake it up to check sensors, send info to Wi-Fi, and if needed switch on RF transmitter.

On the original prototype I turn on the Arduino ever two hours. I then turn on a capacitive proximity sensor and I check the battery level once. I next turn on a potentiometer and temperature sensor for eight seconds while reading them then turn them off.

I then read the proximity sensor. Then I turn on the ESP8266-01 for eight seconds while I post all reading on line. Then off with the ESP.

Depending on the readings from the proximity sensor I turn on the RF transmitter for about one second and then turn off the proximity sensor and put the Arduino back to sleep.

I have made a second prototype in which the coding is the same except I check the battery 50 times in quick succession for a truer average reading. I check the potentiometer ten times for a better average reading and I only wake the Arduino up every six hours instead of two.

The schematic (I'm posting) is basically the same except I have added four small capacitors to smooth out the current. I will circle them in red. Wiring on the first prototype is with .5mm copper wire while on the second prototype the traces on the pcb are .25mm 1 oz copper and some of them have been redone with 28 gauge copper wire.

My problem is that the original prototype will last for seven days before needing to be recharged while the second prototype only makes it four days. Could the capacitors be making a difference, or the sampling of the battery and potentiometer, or is it the wiring size. Is there too much resistance?

If the wiring is the problem what is a good size to have my pcb traces be? Is 2.5mm at 1oz or 2oz enough?

I know there are things I can rewrite in my code to cut times when things are on and cut energy use but I want to know why such a difference in the two prototypes.

Does anyone have any suggestions or questions?
[image]

Comment: that is a somewhat convoluted and hard to read schematic diagram ... looks more like a wiring diagram ... there is no reason why the ground net should be intertwined throughout the diagram

Comment: Can you update your question and tell us exactly what value capacitors you are using. Your question would be better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com, however, the schematic would require improvement. Please read: Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics. Have you tried running the original code (turn on the Arduino ever two hours) on the boards that you added 4 capacitors to?

Comment: Your diagram is hard to follow. Have you measured power consumption during the sleep period? Is it different from the first prototype?

Comment: I highly doubled it's anything to do with you do while it's awake. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the current consumption during sleep. Back of the envelope calculation gives me around 20mA of sleep current. Do you have a multimeter, so you can measure the current? Modify your code so it sleeps all the time, and start measuring. Start unplugging components (if you can safely do so) to see where the current draw is.

Comment: I'm finding that schematic almost impossible to follow. Power and GND placeholders exist for a reason. Use them.

Comment: And... are you *really* using a massive relay to control the power to the ESP-01?!

Comment: Among all the issues that rest of the comments highlighted, you don't need to read the battery voltage for 50 times to get a better reading, your voltage divider simply has too high input impedance to the ADC for getting an accurate measurement, read the datasheet of ATmega328p.

Comment: I updated the schematic.  Hope it helps  I am recharging the batteries and will try various suggestions when they are up.  I am using the HK19 because it was inexpensive.  Since it is only on for 8 seconds every two or six hours I doubt it makes a big difference.  If it were consuming the power it would be consuming more running every 2 hours instead of every 6 hours.  The multiple sampling was suggested and has made it much more consistent.  But I will read datasheet.  I can't see how connected sensors can be problem since I power them off before sleep mode.  But you never know, will thy all.

Comment: An update.  reprogrammed to run every two hrs. with no sensors plugged in.  Power consumption went up by 25%.  Rewrote some code for ESP8266 and other things- saved some power.  Plugged in sensors individually and found something strange.  When the non-contact liquid sensor is turned on and is on it functions properly but when the Arduino goes into sleep mode it continues to consume 110mA.  If the sensor does detect water and stays off and Arduino goes to sleep power consumption is at 20-30 mA.  Checked pins and everything is off.  Can't figure out what is consuming power.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: So I constructed another prototype and now the power consumption is at 30-40 mA when sleep mode whether water detected or not. I know it should be at 20mA but it could be from the voltage booster and the small wire. The next PCB board will have 2.50mm power traces and 1.50mm for all others. We'll see if there is any improvement.